# npm login still required despite AWS CodeArtifact login configuration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-codeartifact

As said in the title, despite a successful npm configuration by AWS CodeArtifact (`Successfully configured npm to use AWS CodeArtifact repository https://xxxxxx.d.codeartifact.xxxx.amazonaws.com/npm/xxxx-npm/`)

and correct configuration in the `.npmrc`

```
registry=https://xxxxxx.d.codeartifact.xxxx.amazonaws.com/npm/xxxx-npm/
//xxxxxx.d.codeartifact.xxxx.amazonaws.com/npm/xxxx-npm/:_authToken=<MY_TOKEN>)
```

Every attempt to install via `npm i` ends in failure saying that the authentication token is invalid and requiring me to `npm login`. And when I do, it prompts this :

```
npm login
npm notice Log in on https://xxxxxx.d.codeartifact.xxxx.amazonaws.com/npm/xxxx-npm/
Username:
```

And I do not know what to provide as username/password since our organization uses a SSO.

Output of `npm -d ping`:

```
npm info using npm@8.0.0
npm info using node@v14.17.6
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/abcdefgh/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/abcdefgh/Documents/Projects/project-backend/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/abcdefgh/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/abcdefgh/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 9ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 9ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 14ms
npm timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 33ms
npm notice PING https://xxxxxx.d.codeartifact.xxxx.amazonaws.com/npm/xxxx-npm/
npm notice PONG 279ms
npm timing command:ping Completed in 279ms
npm timing npm Completed in 468ms
npm info ok
```

I can't figure out where the issue is. Could someone provide some insight?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/npm-auth.html

Comment: What is the output of `npm -d ping`?

Comment: Yes @jordanm, I've used the command to configure the npm correctly : 
`aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository xxxx-npm --domain xxxx--domain-owner xxxxxxxxxx`, still no change

Comment: The output is [here](https://gist.github.com/FaresKi/c5c9c7aa9a78c2afb388cce211412b16) @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: @Fares thank you - p.s. adding it to the Q is much better as comments should be treated as temporary :)

Comment: Does your `.npmrc` actually have a `(` at the beginning or is that a typo?

Comment: Nope, definitely a typo. I'll fix that right away

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238147/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-fares).

Answer (score 2):

It was the f***** npm. I had recently updated from 6.14.12 -> 8 and apparently the whole token and login mechanism breaks down at the new npm.